# npm install not working in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, node-modules

Runnig `npm install` command is giving errors.

THE ERROR:

```
``
PS D:\t> npm install
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: public_services@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.9.4
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"~4.9.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=4.8.2 <4.9" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~15.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"15.0.4" from @angular/localize@15.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!     dev @angular/localize@"^15.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\sayed.hussainullah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sayed.hussainullah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-11T06_57_30_299Z-debug-0.log
``
```

Global angular version:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 15.0.5
Node: 16.16.0
Package Manager: npm 8.17.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1500.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         15.0.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   15.0.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          15.0.5 (cli-only)
```

Package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "public_services",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.4",
        "@angular/common": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/core": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/forms": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/router": "15.0.4",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.1",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "14.0.1",
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "^10.0.3",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
        "angular-archwizard": "7.0.0",
        "angular-feather": "^6.5.0",
        "bootstrap": "5.2.3",
        "chart.js": "^4.1.2",
        "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "3.27.1",
        "date-fns": "2.29.3",
        "gulp": "4.0.2",
        "hopscotch": "0.3.1",
        "intl": "1.2.5",
        "moment": "2.29.4",
        "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.3",
        "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
        "ng2-file-upload": "3.0.0",
        "ng2-img-cropper": "0.9.0",
        "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.2.8",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
        "ngx-chips": "3.0.0",
        "ngx-datatable": "^1.0.3",
        "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^13.0.0",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^7.2.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "16.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
        "nouislider": "15.6.1",
        "prismjs": "1.29.0",
        "resize-observer-polyfill": "1.5.1",
        "rxjs": "7.8.0",
        "screenfull": "6.0.2",
        "sweetalert2": "11.6.16",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
        "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
        "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.0.5",
        "@angular/cli": "~15.0.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/language-service": "~15.0.4",
        "@angular/localize": "^15.0.4",
        "@types/core-js": "2.5.5",
        "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.1",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
        "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
        "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.9.4"

    }
}
```

I have tried:

- delete node modules.
- clear cache.
- unistall node.js and reinstall lower version.
- installed msbuild-tools.

so far non-of these methods worked

Comment: Angular 15.0 doesn't support TypeScript 4.9. Angular 15.1 will.

Comment: Downgraded the typescript version in package.json file to "typescript": "~4.8.4". but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should try running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, in order to ignore dependencies between packages. Nevertheless the root cause of your problem is that your installed angular versions expects typescript version >=4.8.2 and <4.9, but 4.9.4 will be installed. So a solution might be to downgrade your typescript version or update your angular versions.

Comment: Downgraded the typescript version in package.json file to "typescript": "~4.8.4". but still no luck

Comment: running npm install --legacy-peer-deps command is giving the same errors

Comment: npm install --legacy-peer-deps is giving this error: npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\sadat-data\roshan-itsm-front\roshan-itsm-front\node_modules\ng2-jalali-date-picker\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'tweetnacl'
npm ERR! Require stack:

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations of npm's Install Algorithm, So `npm` will refuse to install any package with an identical name to the current package. It will overridden with the `--force` flag, but in most cases can simply be addressed by changing the local package name.

So you need to use `--force` flag to re-install packages again like below:

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: npm install --force Not working

Comment: @SayedHussainullahSadat Did you run mention command?

Comment: Did you run this command in your application directory?

Comment: yeah, this command is giving a long list of errors.

Comment: Yeah, i did run it in application directory

Comment: Can you please share your error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251024/discussion-between-sayed-hussainullah-sadat-and-hardik-solanki).

Comment: @SayedHussainullahSadat delete `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install --force` command again.

Comment: I did so, but it did not work